# How do they create these wooden clocks with LED displays that show through the front panel?

Tags: product-design

[Amazon LED clock product link](https://a.co/d/5qoGMDc)

[image: Wooden LED clock]
Is it a faux wood sticker? Or a thin section? Or is the LED so bright that it shines through.
Any teardown videos of similar applications?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the picture in your question (along with the picture credit / link) so that your readers don't have to follow a link to understand what you are asking and so that your question still makes sense if the link dies. Welcome to E.SE.

Comment: probably yes to all of those ... use your smartphone display to examine the transparency of things like newspaper and other thin items

Comment: Shine a light through plane shavings or mill to a thickness or thinness…

Comment: Buy veneer glue it on top. Done.

Answer (score 1):

The ad description says,

> Made with premium quality black **MDF medium density fiberboard material** ...

The MDF isn't visible so it must be covered with a plastic wood-effect self-adhesive film. A clear plastic bezel in front of the display and mounted flush with the case will support the film and, presumably, be translucent enough that the display can be seen.

I can't see the relevance of the "black" in the description.